# Is there any way to detect attribute change in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
class Test
    attr_accessor :test_attr
    def initialize
        @test_attr = ""
    end

    def test_attr_changed
        p 'test_attr is changed: ' + @test_attr 
    end
end
```

When I change the attribute `:test_attr`:

```
test = Test.new
test.test_attr = "New value"
```

I want it to trigger the `test_attr_changed` function and output:

```
test_attr is changed: New value
```

Is there any way do this in Ruby like QML `onChanged` signal?

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: Do you expect `test_attr_changed` to be called when assigning the same value again, i.e. should it be called upon _assignment_ or upon _change_?

Comment: @Stefan yes, upon assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `attr_accessor :test_attr`.

```
class Test
  attr_reader :test_attr

  def test_attr=(value)
    @test_attr = value
    test_attr_changed
    value
  end
end
```

Comment: It now seems so simple... Good one! Actually, you could stick with `attr_accessor` as `test_attr=` producerd by `attr_accessor` would be overwritten (but i wouldn't advocate that). One could even modify `instance_variable_set`...

Comment: @CarySwoveland That would be quite dangerous. I would rather define a new class method similar to `attr_writer`.

Comment: The return value is superfluous, it is ignored for setter methods.

Comment: @Stefan: To be pedantic: it is ignored for *assignment expressions*, not for setter methods. If you call the method with `public_send`, the value will be returned, only when you use method assignment syntax, the method assignment expression will evaluate to the assigned value, just like any other assignment.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I stand corrected. You're absolutely right – the setter methods of Ruby's core objects (including those created by `attr_...`) do return the assigned value, so it might be a good idea to do the same.

Comment: I had this sentence from the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values) in mind: _"Note that for assignment methods the return value will always be ignored. Instead, the argument will be returned"_ and assumed that it would actually work as advertised. Time to fix the docs.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I would actually advocate for a new `attr_*` method altogether to simplify implementation maybe `attr_watcher`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fairly simple implementation of how you could modularize this functionality

```
module Overlord
  module ClassMethods
    def attr_watcher(*attrs)
      attrs.each do |attr|
        define_method(attr) {instance_variable_get("@#{attr}")}
        define_method("#{attr}=") do |val|
          changes[attr] << {new: val, old: send(attr), when: Time.now}
          instance_variable_set("@#{attr}",val)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  def changes
    @changes ||= Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}
  end
end 

class Test
  include Overlord
  attr_watcher :name
end
```

Then simply

```
t = Test.new
t.changes
#=> {}
t.name = "Mnky"
t.changes
#=> => {:name=>[{:new=>"Mnky", :old=>nil, :when=>2017-08-24 11:17:27 -0400}]}
t.name = "Other"
t.changes[:name] 
#=> [
     {:new=>"Mnky", :old=>nil, :when=>2017-08-24 11:17:27 -0400},
     {:new=>"Other", :old=>"Mnky", :when=>2017-08-24 11:17:58 -0400}]
t.name
#=> "Other"
```